# Access query select

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I need help with a query on Access database that I don't know how to do.
What I have is a database with a table diseases that stores diseases names and ID another one called Symptoms that stores Symptoms names and ID, and another one called SymptomsDiseases where I associate symptoms to a given disease. What I want to do is get all diseases that have a given set of symptoms for example diseases with symptoms with ID 3, 4 and 5. What is the SQL Query that I should do to solve this? These are the tables and fields:

1) Diseases

IdDisease

DiseaseName

2) Symptoms

IdSymptom

SymptonName

3) SymptomsDiseases

IdDiseases_fk

IdSymptoms_fk

=> In this table I would have for example:

IdDisease_fk || IdSymptoms_fk

6            || 4

6            || 5

6            || 3

6            || 7

6            || 8

4            || 10

4            || 11

4            || 4

4            || 5

4            || 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of technique is called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  a.IdDisease,
        a.DiseaseName
FROM    Diseases AS a
        INNER JOIN SymptomsDiseases as B
            ON a.IdDisease = b.IdDiseases_fk
WHERE   b.IdSymptoms_fk IN (3,4,5)               -- <<== list of ID of Symptoms
GROUP   BY a.IdDisease, a.DiseaseName
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3                             -- <<== number of symptoms
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Great answer! That's exactly what I needed :) Looks like I need to work on my SQL skills.